# Running Google Script without updating spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple scripts that I want to run on data in my spreadsheet. Some of the data is populated by random number function.. so they change every time the spreadsheet is updated/edited.

It seems that my scripts update the spreadsheet even if it doesn't explicitly edit any cells. This causes all of the data to change mid-script and mess things up.

Is there any way to stop the spreadsheet from updating while a script is running?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  You'll need to come up with a way of structuring the retrieval and updating of data, and the timing of the flow of events.  You could check for certain conditions, and halt the script if need be.  You could set key cell values from a script, rather than a function in the cell.